# Search for budgeting app / web service handling automated sync and multiple currencies

Tags: budget, software, recommendation

I went trough quite a few budgeting web services / phone apps with the features below and could only found one (PocketSmith), but it suddenly stopped syncing EU banks. It would be great to have any suggestion on a budgeting service with the following features:

- [required] both web platform and mobile app
- [required] automated sync with banks from US and EU, or at least from EU
- [required] handling of multiple currencies (so that all transactions appear with the same base currency, whatever their original currency)
- [required] categories and subcategories, customizable
- [required] import of transaction files with categories (and ideally subcategories) information
- [required] budgeting
- [required] multi-users or at least possibility of several users using the same account at the same time
- [preferred] with an API

Any suggestion would be very welcome,

Michael

Comment: I haven't found any app that can sync with banks from more than one EU country. In my experience you can find a few apps for in some countries that can be synced with most banks from those countries but that's it. I doubt there is an existing app that can sync with banks from multiple countries AND fulfil all the other criteria here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MartínBasterrechea, there are actually MANY apps now which can sync with banks from more than one EU country due to the newly available APIs (cf. for example PocketSmith, Linxo, Wallet, Bankin', Budget Insight, Spendee, etc.).

Comment: As written, this will likely be closed as [off-topic](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), since questions asking for product/service recommendations are not allowed. They tend to become inaccurate/obsolete quickly, and allowing them invites spam.

Comment: This question is off-topic for our site and will be closed. However, it would be a good question for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you @BenMiller for suggesting a place to post it instead of just closing it silently. I posted it in the site you recommended, so it can be closed here anytime now.

Comment: [Repost on Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/68945/83)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Wallet from Budget Bakers](https://budgetbakers.com/) (I don't have any affiliation with this company, I'm just a user). Though, I think you should bye premium if you really need all the feature you mentioned in you question.

You can check if the app syncs with your bank here : https://budgetbakers.com/bank-to-sync

Comment: Thank you @Fourat, i actually checked it first and gave up due to serious bugs when importing files (it would silently not import, or silently import twice, with a mess being created to clean up these bugs), but i'll try again